# What are the possible values for action-status of Commission Junction

Tags: commission-junction

What are the possible values for "action-status" response field of Commission Detail Service (REST) of Commission Junction? I tried searching their API help, but did not find the info I needed. I need to know all possible status values, based on which I have to perform specific tasks in my program. Anybody know where I can find this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible values for "action-status" could be:

1. locked
2. new
3. extended
4. closed

Some of the status answers them selves.

1. new: When a single entity in commission detail report is newly created,
2. extended: When there are any changes to an existing commission detail,
3. locked: This is the final status, where we can process the commission detail as final detail,
4. Not sure about closed commission detail status, may be when an commission detail already processed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be great if you can also provide me what this each status mean. I want to know which of these means "approved transaction" and "rejected transaction". I dont know why CJ dont provide this simple information in their API documentation and they dont even answer the questions posted in their customer support web page. Pathetic CJ!

Comment: Some of the status answers them selves.
1. new: When a single entity in commission detail report is created newly,
2. extended: When there are any changes to an existing commission detail,
3. locked: This is the final status, where we can process the commission detail as final detail,
4. Not sure about closed commission detail, may be when an commission detail is older & already processed.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the forum conversation here:

https://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/142060-when-does-cj-pay.html

and here:

http://www.abestweb.com/forums/showthread.php?62669-What-are-quot-new-quot-quot-extended-quot-and-quot-Locked-quot-commissions

It appears that:

- **Extended** = Advertiser has moved to extend the closing period from the default.  So if you were originally going to get paid on Aug 15th, and the advertiser extended commission closing date, then you're not going to get paid until a later time.  The advertiser can only extend a commission once for 30 days.
- **Locked** = Advertiser has insufficient funds to pay the commission earned.  The ball is now in CJ's court to settle up with the advertiser to try to claim the funds so you'll get paid.  Depending on your accounting rules, you may want to mark these funds as written off after some period.  The second post referenced above is very old (2005) but claims that locked is a default status akin to Closed.
- **Closed** = Funds have been settled at CJ (advertiser has paid) and you're due these funds when the next payment cycle hits and if you're over the minimum payout threshold.